# how to use if else c++

Tags: c++, if-statement

How do you provide a condition in the `if` statement, if the variable is an integer data type then it will be displayed, and if the variable is any other data type then something else will be displayed?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    char pilih,pilih2;
    int p, l, a, t, r,ulang = 4;
    float luas1, luas2, luas3, keliling1, keliling2, keliling3, phi = 3.14;
    
    while (ulang > 0) {
        pilihUlang:
        cout << "Pilih jenis bangun datar berikut :\n 1. Persegi panjang\n 2. Segitiga sama sisi\n 3. Lingkaran" << endl;
        cout << "Masukan pilihan anda [1/2/3] : ";
        cin >> pilih;
        system("cls");
        switch (pilih) {
        case '1':
            system("color 07");
            cout << "Luas Dan Keliling Persegi Panjang" << endl;
            cout << "Masukan Panjang = ";
            cin >> p;
            if (?) { // <-- here
                cout << "Masukan Lebar = ";
                cin >> l;
                system("cls");
                cout << "Luas dan keliling Persegi Panjang dengan panjang " << p << " dan lebar " << l << ", yaitu :" << endl;
                luas1 = p * l;
                keliling1 = 2 * (p + l);
                cout << "Luas = " << luas1 << endl;
                cout << "Keliling = " << keliling1 << endl;
                cout << "Sisa bisa memilih ulang " << ulang - 1 << " kali." << endl;
                break;
            }
            else {
                //...
            }
```

Comment: `cin >> p;`  the variable `p` is always an integer regardless of what you type. The input will fail if it can't be converted to an int. You could do `if (cin >> p) { // A valid int was typed} else { cin.clear(); }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [istream::operator>> man page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt):

> If extraction fails (e.g. if a letter was entered where a digit is
> expected), zero is written to value and failbit is set.

So, your function could test the [cin.good()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/good) method to see if the `>>` operation was successful, like this:

```
cin >> p;
if (cin.good()) {
   cout << "The integer you typed was " << p << endl;
} else {
   cout << "Hey, that wasn't an integer!" << endl;
}
```

Comment: You should use `if (cin >> p)` instead

Comment: `cin.good()` seems more self-explanatory to me, but to each his own.

Comment: There is a subtle but important difference. If `operator>>` encounters end-of-stream but otherwise is able to extract valid input, `good()` will return false and you will skip processing the input, whereas interpreting the stream in a boolean context (like `if`) will return true, allowing the input to be processed.